# Populating a form with names from a .txt file

Tags: javascript, html, text

I am trying to populate a dropdown list with a bunch of names that are stored in a .txt in the same directory as the HTML code. Each name is on a new line of this file and"names" is the id of the dropdown that will store the names.

Upon loading the page, the list is not populated at all. Any guidance would be awesome.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var select = document.getElementById("names");
    var textFile = "/names.txt";        
    jQuery.get(textFile, function(textFileData) {  
        var EachLineInTextFile = textFileData.responseText.split(",");
        for (var i = 0, len = EachLineInTextFile.length; i < len; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.text = option.value = EachLineInTextFile[i];
            select.add(option, 0);
        };
    };
};
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the html as well showing the `select`?

Comment: For right now, I'm just trying to populate the list, so its `<form> <select id="names" name="names"></select></form>`

Comment: your var "EachLineInTextFile" is not holding each line, but rather evey column in the sheet with lines thrown away or concated to some of the cols. split by "\n" for lines, then split each line by ","

Comment: I just tried changing the `.split(",")` to `.split("\n")` and still no luck

Comment: Is this an exact copy of your function?  There doesn't seem to be a closing parenthesis for your `jQuery.get(` call.

Comment: Are you sure `textFileData` contains the contents of the file? Add `console.log(textFileData)` to confirm.

Comment: This is an exact copy. I just closed the parenthesis after the second closed squiggly bracket on the 3rd to last line. I was hoping it was a simple silly mistake but it did not work

Comment: `textFileData` would be the contents of the file, not `textFileData.responseText`

Comment: Have you checked the Javascript console for errors? That error should be causing an error about "Cannot read property 'split' of undefined".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the major issue was that I needed a better version of jquery. Thank you everyone for your help!

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var select = document.getElementById("names");
        var textFile = "/names.txt";       
        jQuery.get(textFile, function(textFileData) {  
            window.alert(textFileData); 
            var EachName= textFileData.split("\n");

                 for (var i = 0, len = EachName.length; i < len; i++) {
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.text = option.value = EachName[i];
                    select.add(option, 0);
        };
       });
    };
</script>
```